# Text over an image with CSS

Tags: css

First I want to say I am quite a newbie with CSS.
Without changing a lot of my code I would like to have text over an image.
My current code is:

```css
#container {
 width: 1010px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#left-box {
 width: 681px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 29px;
}

#data {
 width: 206px;
 height: 140px;
 background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-box">
    <div id="data">
   <img src="img/img1.jpg" />
   <<<< here I want put some text, which should be over the image >>>>
   <h2 class="h2-data"><a href="#">Some text</a></h2>
   <p class="stats">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding some code which I found from Google, but the text is appearing at the top of the website when I use absolute as position. And with relative the text is under the image, but not OVER the image.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: You could have the image as a `background`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: relative` for the block enclosing the image and `position: absolute` for the text after assigning a class to it.

```css
#container {
  width: 1010px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#left-box {
  width: 681px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 29px;
}
#data {
  width: 206px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  top: 0;
  left: 100;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-box">
    <div id="data">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140"></img>
      <div class="text">
        <<<< here I want put some text, which should be over the image>>>></div>
      <h2 class="h2-data"><a href="#">Some text</a></h2>
      <p class="stats">text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible, I want to do it without using the image as background. I have a lot of #data in the website, every #data item has a different image.

Answer (score 0):

maybe so

```css
#container {
 width: 1010px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#left-box {
 width: 681px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 29px;
}

#data {
 width: 206px;
 height: 140px;
 background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
}

#data img{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
#data .text{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-box">
    <div id="data">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" />
        <div class="text">
        <<<< here I want put some text, which should be over the image >>>>
   <h2 class="h2-data"><a href="#">Some text</a></h2>
   <p class="stats">text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```